# adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing

Tags: android, react-native, expo

Couldn't start project on Android:

```
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing...
could not read OK from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
adb.exe: failed to check server version: cannot connect to daemon
```

i have installed android platform development  tools but it still doesn't work even after changing Genymotion settings to use my android Software development kit instead of its default android tools

Comment: Maybe my related Q/A helps somebody who didn't find an answer here: https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232860/340401

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In my case the problem occurred because of two ADB paths. I actually moved my Android SDK (due to lack of space in system drive) from one path to another and set up the environment variables accordingly. Starting and killing the server didn't help so I followed this thread in [GitHub](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/527#issuecomment-496870244)

But unlike that thread, instead of replacing the files in scrcpy folder, I replaced the files in `C:\Program Files\Genymobile\Genymotion\tools`[image: copied the files from sdk\platform-tools]

[image: replaced the files in the Genymobile\Genymotion\tools]

And it started working after that

Comment: You saved me 2 hours of Googling dude, works like a charm.

Comment: Thanks a lot dude...You saved lot of my time

Answer (score 0):

kill the adb server with the flowing command

```
package: com.technobd.topbdnews 

adb uninstall com.technobd.topbdnews // run this command replacing the package name
```

Comment: which package name specifically

Comment: Your app package name

Comment: now i get this error could not read ok from ADB Server
* failed to start daemon
error: cannot connect to daemon
- waiting for device -
error: cannot connect to daemon

Comment: plus when i do expo start i get the same error as before

Comment: You can try kill server and restart the server again
**adb kill-server**
**adb start-server**
OR
**1. adb kill-server**
**2. sudo cp ~/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb /usr/bin/adb**
**3. sudo chmod +x /usr/bin/adb**
**4. adb start-server **
Try to execute the above 4  commands one by one.

Comment: i am on a windows pc so sudo cp command are not recognizable

Comment: Ignore ***sudo* for windows.  From your Android studio command line run the above command.