# adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41)

Tags: android

**Android Studio** is unable to install an application throwing the following error:

```
adb server version (40) doesn't match this client (41); killing
```

I tried answers from [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56948676/adb-server-version-40-doesnt-match-this-client-41-killing) but they didn't work for me.

Comment: Maybe, this helps? https://android.stackexchange.com/a/232860/340401

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ADB server version (36) doesn't match this client (39) {Not using Genymotion}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43050370/adb-server-version-36-doesnt-match-this-client-39-not-using-genymotion)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please invalidate the cache and restart the android studio.

Answer (score 0):

I have Android SDK and tools already installed and adb is present in `$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/adb`

In my case, just removing adb from my `/usr/local/bin/adb` which I got from `adb version` using `rm /usr/local/bin/adb` solved the issue.

Reference: https://thedarksource.com/how-to-solve-this-adb-server-version-doesnt-match-this-client-error-in-android/

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve this issue is that,

1 - download the latest version of platform-tools from here [platform-tools](https://developer.android.com/tools/releases/platform-tools),
2 - in your computer go to
C:\Users"YOURCOMPUTERNAME"\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk
3 - change your old platform-tools file to platform-tools77 just to back it up
4 - Put the new platform-tools you downloaded from step 1.

That all !  if it not works download another version (older) from same link and try again till you find the one match your software.